# How to conditionally add colors in datatable with R?

Tags: r, datatable

In a datatable with R, I'd like to display the values of columns "val1" and "val2" in red.

If these values are more than twice greater than or more than twice less than the value of "mymean" for each each row.

Example:

```r
library(tibble)
library(DT)

mydf <- tribble(
  ~x,  ~mymean, ~val1, ~val2,
  "a", 3, 2, 8,
  "b", 5, 6, 1
)
# Using formatStyle() ?
datatable(mydf) |> 
  formatStyle(
    c("val1","val2"),
    color = "red"
  )
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Some leads here of things to explore: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/05/mimic-excels-conditional-formatting-in-r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two columns which contain the information whether the value is in the desired interval or not. Then hide them in the datatable command in the `columnDefs` and use `styleEqual` in `formatStyle` to define the colors:

```
library(tibble)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

mydf <- tribble(
  ~x,  ~mymean, ~val1, ~val2,
  "a", 3, 2, 8,
  "b", 5, 6, 1
)

mydf <- mydf %>% mutate(val_1_in_interval = ifelse(val1 >= 0.5*mymean & val1 <= 2*mymean,1,0))
mydf <- mydf %>% mutate(val_2_in_interval = ifelse(val2 >= 0.5*mymean & val2 <= 2*mymean,1,0))

datatable(mydf,options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE,targets = c(5,6))))) |> 
  formatStyle(c("val1","val2"),c("val_1_in_interval","val_2_in_interval"),color = styleEqual(c(0,1),c('red','black')))
```